# Need help getting user friendly URL

Tags: url-rewriting, user-friendly

I trying to get a user friendly URL.

My current link is this:
http://www.norwegianfashion.no/designers/?designer=Batlak-og-Selvig&bid=9
What I want is this
http://www.norwegianfashion.no/designers/Batlak-og-Selvig/

What do I need to do in order to get this URL?
Anything I can do in .htaccess file?

**Update**
I'm using Wordpress which has it's own permalink structure. I'm not sure if it's possible to add URL-rewrite?

I'm also looking at this link: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting/2 , but I'm not very succesfull.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with the htaccess file in a very similar way to get rid of the question mark using a RewriteRule. Hopefully someone can chime in with a better answer but the format I use on my site is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PAGE=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried `RewriteRule ^/designer/([A-Z]+)$ /designers.php?designer=$1 [NC]`, but the URL in the browser is still the same :(

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you set it up, you could use the post name for the permalink. So, in the admin area of wordpress, you'd go to Pemalinks, and use a custom one. Then, type in %postname% in the input box, and that'll create the permalink by post. So, if you create a new page/post called "Test", the url would be -
norwegianfashion.no/Test

Comment: I'm alread y using custom permalinks. You can see that if you brows my site. This however are custom page retrieving info from custom DB, hence not able to use WP permalink structure. I most probably have to add additional permalink rewrites.